# dotnet framework 2.0 sp2 breaks CLR integration in SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql, sqlclr

It appears that CLR integration does not like Dotnet framework 2.0 sp2. I am getting the following error message when trying to run code that depends on the clr.

```
Msg 6510, Level 16, State 11, Line 1
Common Language Runtime (CLR) v2.0.50727 not installed properly. The CLR is required to use SQL/CLR features.
```

I have verfied with the dotnet verification tool that the dotnet framework for all versions installed work.

I have only found possibly one hint that this is whats causing the issue. I would think thought that if this was the case more people would be screaming. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to track this down better. We have a few systems that are relying on this implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It almost sounds like a corrupt install of v2.0.50727.  I would try to reinstall that version and the SP.  Can you run a custom .net app compiled for that version on that machine?

Comment: the MS verification tool runs a custom app as part of its process, but i think it runs it against sp2. Do you mean specifically for dotnet framework 2.0 no sp?

Comment: Our server rebooted overnight unexpectanly. I tested the clr process report and it is now working, so maybe something was corrupt, we had an issue with zombie processes.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working.  I should have been clearer with my answer.  I meant to reinstall .Net framework v2.0.50727 and any SP's/hotfixes (to get you to where you were before reinstalling).

Answer (score 1):

Restarting the SQL Server service got me past this problem.

The CLR had been enabled using the...

```
sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;
GO
reconfigure
GO
```

...statements but until the SQL Server service was restarted none of the CLR features could be used.